# SQL Server query that can never work is accepted in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
create procedure tempsproc
as 
    select t1.c1
    from #t 
    join t2 on #t.c2 = t3.c3
```

The select clause references a table which is not mentioned in the from clause.
I have heard of deferred name resolution but I do not see how the above select could ever work no matter what tables are existing at runtime.

The on clause also references tables which are not mentioned in the from clause.

The above SQL compiles without error.

The problem only comes to light at run time - not what you want

What do I need to do in order for the above procedure to be rejected by SQL Server at compile time?

PS: this is on a SQL Server 2008 R2 sp3 system

Comment: "*The problem only comes to light at run time - not what you want*"  Actually, this problem (like most others) *should* come to light when you test it.  Are you not doing that?

Answer (score 5):

This *could* work (from the SQL compilers perspective) if a column named `t1` is added to either of the tables and a type *method* named `c1` were also added to the database.

Since the compiler does not know what names and methods might be added in the future, the rules of Deferred-Name Resolution say that it has to accept it.

In short, it's *not* a syntax-error so it will *NOT* be rejected.

---

Problems like this really should be picked-up during debugging, but if you want to catch when you are parsing and saving your stored procedures, you can get it mostly done by doing something like this:

```
create procedure tempsproc
as 
    select t1.c1
    from #t 
    join t2 on #t.c2 = t3.c3
go
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXEC tempsproc;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
go
```

---

***TYPE METHODS***

I have been asked to explain about the Type Methods, so here it is.

Most of the newer data types, such as XML and Spatial include special methods that can only be used on these data types.  Here's an example from Microsoft:

```
CREATE TABLE SpatialTable   
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),  
    GeomCol1 geometry,   
    GeomCol2 AS GeomCol1.STAsText() );  
GO  

INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeomCol1)  
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (100 100, 20 180, 180 180)', 0));
```

This shows two very different method formats (`GeomCol1.STAsText()` and `geometry::STGeomFromText('...')`), which highlights another point.

This syntax was to comply with certain standards (OGC in this case).  The XML methods have to comply with a different standard.  Other data types they add in the future may have to comply with still other standards, which means that they have to be pretty flexible about what the allowable syntax for a method might be, including whether or not it has any parenthesis.

Finally, you may wonder, "*But don't they know ahead of time what data-type methods exist?*"  Surprisingly, the answer is "NO", because SQL Server allows new data-types to be added to existing servers and databases.  So, for instance, XML data-types were originally an optional add-on(extension) to SQL Server (they were then built-in to the next major release).  Further I believe (not sure) that customers and third-parties can also make their own and add them to an existing database.

Comment: Could you please  give more detail on what would have to happen for this not to error at runtime? I am not familiar with type methods. But even if you are right this behaviour should be opt in. The default should be that syntax is checked against what exists now not what crazy things might happen in the future. Is there no way to have it behave in a sane fashion?

Comment: @user2849221 What you are objecting to is the essence of Deferred Name Resolution.  There are many reasons why it is a *very good* thing.  I have worked in environments that did not have it and they were insufferable, especially when it came to development and deployment.

Comment: As for type methods, they are an obscure feature (mostly for XML) that may be used more in the future.

Comment: without specific contradiction I stand by my statement that the above stored procedure could never run without error and so should be rejected. As for working in environments where you don't know what tables will exist from one moment to another, that must have been challenging

Comment: @user2849221 OK, it appears that you are not really asking a question but trying to make an argument. This is not the forum for that. If you want to argue about Microsoft's design decisions, you should take it up with them. This forum is for specific programming questions, which I have answered. What more would you like me to provide with respect to "specific contradiction"? This sounds like you think that I am making up the part about possible future methods, how can I help you with that?

Comment: @user2849221 I have added some more explanation about data-type methods.